# Will I experience any nasty shocks moving Django from Postgres to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql

If I'm developing a Django site with Postgres and intend to deploy to MySQL, am I in for any nasty surprises?

[Yes, I have read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306048/django-sqlite-for-dev-mysql-for-prod)! Some answers concerned the lack of type and constraint safety in SQLite. As I understand it, Postgres exceeds MySQL in strictness and correctness. The potential issues that I can think of aren't an issue in this case.

Comment: Even though you read that link it would still be nice to know what use case causes you to develop on one database and deploy on another. More headaches(not logical) than it's worth and I say that from experience.

Comment: The reason is working with a client's system (MySQL) but not wanting to have to install MySQL and get the bindings working (not easy) on my dev system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this and one big headache I came across was case sensitivity. MySQL wasn't case sensitive, Postgres was. When I ported across my data (I used fixtures) I ran into issues with django-tagging thinking it had duplicate tags. I had to hack it up to fix but in retrospect I should have just stuck with the same database.

Answer (score 1):

One problem I had was that MySQL [doesn't support rolling back DDL changes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/858/why-wont-some-dbmses-allow-to-rollback-certain-ddl-statements).
Of course it may not be a problem for you :)