# Can the AppEngine SQLite datastore work with Django SQLite backend?

Tags: google-app-engine

With the release of AppEngine 1.7.3, soon the SQLite datastore stub will be default for the Python SDK. Any plans to give users using Django and Cloud SQL the ability to use the SQLLite datastore with the SQLLite Django backend locally?

Comment: I'd suggest asking this question in the discussion forum: https://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine

Comment: @DanHolevoet I wouldn't say that. Stackoverflow is the new official community support destination for GAE. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/Z6XN_64cA7w/Jf1OcUK4cF0J

Comment: The group remains open for general discussion and for topics not a good fit for the Stack Overflow model (like this one).

Comment: I think it's [not smart to use sqlite locally and mysql in prod](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306048/django-sqlite-for-dev-mysql-for-prod). There are some mysql options in dev_appserver.py that are called `Cloud SQL (rdbms) stub`. Did you try those?

Comment: I agree, for a large project I would use the same db, but I'm working on something small with a large group of people who only know html, css, and js. Having them get mysql setup locally just to run Django instead of using the built-in SQLite would be really nice.