# Accelerate unittest in Django

Tags: django, performance, unit-testing

I found it is slow to perform unittest especially with database operations in Django.

It went through the whole process of creating database,tables,fixtures, then testing and finally destroying them.

It even took me almost half a minute to do all these stuff.

Without considering the speed of my machine, is there any alternative to speed up unittest in Django or any accelerating tips?

Comment: Since you're saying it takes ~30s to run the tests, I'm assuming you are already running your app's tests only (not the whole django test suite). With that assumption in place, the bottleneck to remove is probably sqlite (which is quite slow). I'd recommend installing a local postgres/mysql server and use that instead.

Comment: @OwenNelson: curiously, SQLite is a great speed boost for Django tests.  easily chops a 45-50 sec test suite to 7-10 secs

Comment: @OwenNelson, I am using MySQL, not on my machine, but on a remote host in LAN. Maybe, moving the db server on my machine will be good. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025011/increase-speed-for-mysql-table-creation-in-django

Comment: @Javier I'm surprised to hear sqlite is faster for you. Generally speaking, since it's a serverless, disk-based implementation you will run into disk/file contention issues (waiting for locks) when dealing with large numbers of inserts/updates/deletes (which are natural with large sets of fixtures). In a case where you have fixture data, I've often found an actual RMDBs to be much faster. **I'm saying this assuming that the fixture data is large enough to not run sqlite in :memory:, of course.

Comment: @MarkLavin nailed it. Ramdisk largely solves most of your speed woes.

Answer (score 2):

What I do is switch to SQLite when I want to run tests. It takes a lot less time to setup the test database in SQLite.

You can easily accomplish this by using a modified settings file:

```
$ python manage.py test my_app --settings=test_settings
```

Or in my case,

```
$ python manage.py test my_app --settings=settings.test
```

as I use the "settings as a package" scheme.

Comment: Thanks, I will try. But before that, how can I deal with the incompatiblility between MySQL and SQLite, because many of the db operations are done in raw sql.

Comment: @xiaohan2012, unfortunately this solution won't help you with that.

Answer (score 2):

You can accelerate tests runing them in [sqlite db stored in memory](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html)

```
    DATABASES['default'] = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': ':memory:'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this article](http://www.daveoncode.com/2013/09/23/effective-tdd-tricks-to-speed-up-django-tests-up-to-10x-faster/). It has many useful tips like:

- Changing the password hashing function to MD5 (made huge improvement for me).
- Using a faster in-memory DB.
- Disabling unneeded apps and middleware.